# .NET XmlDocument: How to create element with no prefix, but namespace with prefix?

Tags: .net, xml, xmldocument

I'm using .NET's XmlDocument class because I need to edit XML documents dynamically.

I'm trying to create an element that looks like this:

```
<element xmlns:abc="MyNamespace">
```

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("abc", "MyNamespace");

XmlNode declarationNode = xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xml.AppendChild(declarationNode);

// Create a root element with a default namespace.
XmlNode rootNode = xml.CreateElement("root", "rootNamespace");
xml.AppendChild(rootNode);

XmlNode containerNode = xml.CreateElement("container", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
rootNode.AppendChild(containerNode);

// Create the element node in question:
XmlNode elementNode = xml.CreateElement("element", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

XmlAttribute attr = xml.CreateAttribute("abc", "def", nsmgr.LookupNamespace("abc"));

elementNode.Attributes.Append(attr);

containerNode.AppendChild(elementNode);
```

Here is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootNode xmlns="MyNamespace">
  <container>
    <element abc:def="" xmlns:abc="MyNamespace" />
  </container>
</rootNode>
```

It appears the *attribute* attr is causing both "abc:def=""" and "xmlns:abc="MyNamespace"" to be set--all I want is for the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working here

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("abc", "MyNamespace");

    XmlNode declarationNode = xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    xml.AppendChild(declarationNode);

    // Create a root element with a default namespace.
    XmlElement rootNode = xml.CreateElement("root");
    rootNode.SetAttribute("xmlns:abc", "MyNamespace");

    xml.AppendChild(rootNode);

    XmlNode containerNode = xml.CreateElement("container", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
    rootNode.AppendChild(containerNode);

    // Create the element node in question:
    XmlNode elementNode = xml.CreateElement("abc", "element", "MyNamespace");

    containerNode.AppendChild(elementNode);

    Console.Write(rootNode.OuterXml);
```

and the output is

```
 <root xmlns:abc="MyNamespace"><container><abc:element /></container></root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your namespaces at the top level.

See this post to get an example :
[How do I add multiple namespaces to the root element with XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331568/how-do-i-add-multiple-namespaces-to-the-root-element-with-xmldocument)

Comment: Thanks for the link--but I think part of my problem is that the attribute in question is "xmlns", which implies a namespace, and not just any attribute that we could define.

Comment: If you declare your namespaces with prefixes at the toplevel of your document, the namespace will not been output at each node of your XML.

<element xmlns:abc="MyNamespace"><abc:bobo/></<element>  

This output doesn't need the namespace spec as it has been declared on a top level of your xml

Comment: if <element> is your root element then you can only have this...

but if your complete XML is like 

<elements>
<abc:element>
</abc:element>
</elements>

you have to specify namespace on the elements and it will not be repeated on every abc;element :=)

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Laurent Lequenne. I updated my source, as it still doesn't appear to be behaving the way I expect. Setting an attribute is causing two namespace decorations to be added?